# How to return two different variable in c++?

Tags: c#, dll

dll C++

```
extern "C"  
{
     __declspec(dllexport) int mainfun()
     {
         return x;
     }
}
```

In C#

```
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mainfun();
```

I only know how to return and call one variable from C++ to C#. I am writing a program where i need to call two different varables in C# from c++ dll 
(*like* return x,y;). Please i need help.

EDIT1:

In C++

```
struct Point
{
    int count_err;
    int statement;
} obj;
extern "C"  
{
     __declspec(dllexport) Point mainfun()
     {
         return obj;
     }
}
```

In C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct Point 
{ 
   public int errsize; 
   public int statmnt; 
} 
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]    
public static extern Point mainfun();

errsize = mainfun();
statmnt = mainfun();
```

Here errsize is giving an error-"the name 'errsize' does not exist in the current context".. What to do?

EDIT2:

In C#

```
total_errors.Text = p.errsize.ToString();
```

giving same error-"the name 'p' does not exist in the current." context"

Comment: Return a struct or an array/pointer.

Comment: @Bauss - __declspec(dllexport) pair<int, int> mainfun(). Can i write like this

Comment: Only a single *value* can be return. It can be a complex value (struct, object, packed; or indirect to such).

Comment: @AmneshGoel - Can you tell me how to call this in c#?

Comment: But when you will change to a list in C# then at the same time, you would need to re-write your C++ function too. And in C++ you cannot use a list pair value.. since this dependency exist, you cannot use list here.

Answer (score 2):

Define new struct or array of data. Something like this:

C++:

```
struct Point
{
    int count_err;
    int statement;
} obj;
extern "C"  
{
     __declspec(dllexport) Point mainfun()
     {
         return obj;
     }
}
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct Point 
{ 
   public int errsize; 
   public int statmnt; 
} 
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]    
public static extern Point mainfun();

Point p = mainfun();
var errsize = p.errsize;
var statmnt = p.statmnt;
```

Comment: -  Can i write like this ---__declspec(dllexport) pair<int, int> mainfun() { return make_pair<int,int>(x,y); }

Comment: @AbdulArif as i know - no, because `pair` is not a struct, and you need to return pointers...  much better to declare custom struct and return strongly declared types

Comment: @Backs Your code will throw an error of `type conversion`. Because your `mainfun()` is returning a `point` (structure) and return type is `int`. You may need to change that in order that to work.

Comment: - Error i'm encountering 
error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union

What went wrong i wrote has it is?

Comment: @AbdulArif i changed declaration of Point, look at it

Comment: @AbdulArif do you use C++ or plain C?

Comment: I'm writing program in C++

Comment: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] public struct Point { public int errsize; public int statmnt; } [DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] public static extern Point mainfun(); errsize = mainfun()` where errsize is giving an error the name 'errsize' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @AbdulArif add it in your question

Comment: Ok...got it..Thanks but how to use `var errsize` any where again in the program

Comment: @AbdulArif man, really? you should learn about fields and properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173118(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First understand that if you want to **return more than one value** from any function, then you will need an object which can hold multiple values like *struct, class object, list* etc. But in your case you cannot use `LIST` or `KeyValuePairList` of `C#` because you have direct dependency with `C++ code`.

So use structure which is same in both the platforms. Now first you need to create a suitable data structure and change the return type of `mainfun()` when you are calling it as follows..

```
public struct abc {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern abc mainfun();
```

Now in your `C++ library`, add the data structure and change the function definition.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} abc;

extern "C"  
{
     __declspec(dllexport) abc mainfun()
     {
         abc obj;
         obj.x = 1;
         obj.y = 2;
         return obj;
     }
}
```

Comment: - Error i'm encountering 
error C2065: 'obj' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.a' must have class/struct/union

What went wrong i wrote has it is?